# Mapping slugs from database in routing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have to support url friendly structure for a project.

There is multiple tables with a slug column, in cakephp how can I route the slug to a controller in the most efficient way.

At first I was checking if slug exist in a table, if slug exist use the route:

```
    $c = TableRegistry::get('cateogories');
    $result= $c->find()->select(['id'])->where(['url'=>$slug])->toArray();
    if(count($result) > 0) {
        $routes->connect(
            '/:slug',
            ['controller' => 'Categories', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => $result[0]['id']]
        );
    }
```

The problem being that I have multiple checks like the one above and each one is being ran even if a route prior matches (doesn't need to be ran so extra querys are being called).

So how can I add a conditional statement of some sort so that it only checks if the route matches if none of the prior ones have.

Comment: And there will never be any conflicts, ie, the slug is unique over multiple tables?

Comment: Yes there would be no conflicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to go for a custom route class that handles this. While you could query the data in your routes files, this is

- not overly test friendly
- not very DRY
- not safe for reverse routing

The latter point means that when not connecting all routes, trying to generate a URL from a route array for a non-connected route might trigger an exception, or match the wrong route.

With a custom route class you could simply pass the model in the options when connecting the routes, and in the route class after [**parsing the URL**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Routing.Route.Route.html#_parse), query that model for the given slug, and return `false` or the parsed data accordingly.It's really simple, just have a look at what the existing route classes do.

Here's a very basic example which should be pretty self-explantory.

**src/Routing/Route/SlugRoute.php**

```
namespace App\Routing\Route;

use Cake\Routing\Route\Route;
use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;

class SlugRoute extends Route
{
    use LocatorAwareTrait;

    public function parse($url)
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url);
        if (!$params ||
            !isset($this->options['model'])
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        $count = $this
            ->tableLocator()
            ->get($this->options['model'])
            ->find()
            ->where([
                'slug' => $params['slug']
            ])
            ->count();

        if ($count !== 1) {
            return false;
        }

        return $params;
    }
}
```

This example assumes that in the controller, you'd use the slug to retrieve the record. If you'd wanted to have the ID passed, then instead of using `count()`, you could fetch the ID and pass it along in the parsed data, like:

```
$params['pass'][] = $id;
```

It would then end up being passed as the second argument of the controller action.

**routes.php**

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view'],
    [
        'pass' => ['slug'],
        'routeClass' => 'SlugRoute',
        'model' => 'Articles'
    ]
);

$routes->connect(
    '/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'Categories', 'action' => 'view'],
    [
        'pass' => ['slug'],
        'routeClass' => 'SlugRoute',
        'model' => 'Categories'
    ]
);

// ...
```

This would first check the `Articles` model, then the `Categories` model, etc., and stop once one of the routes finds a record for the given slug.

---

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Custom Route Classes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes)**
- **[API > \Cake\Routing\Route::parse()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Routing.Route.Route.html#_parse)**
- **[Source > \Cake\Routing\Route](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/3.1.5/src/Routing/Route)**