# Make CakePHP consider two different routes/models for same path?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a website that has users and entries, both of which are stored in a database. Every entry has its own page, using its slug, and every user has a public profile, using its username. Their respective URLs might look something like this:

- Entry: `https://example.com/hello-world`
- User: `https://example.com/test-user`

Refactoring said website with CakePHP 3.4 (the original being built with “vanilla” PHP), I implemented the following routes:

```
$routes->connect('/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'Entries', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['pass' => ['slug']]
);

$routes->connect('/:username',
    ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['pass' => ['username']]
);
```

The entry pages work like a charm — no problem there — but when I try to access a user profile, Cake throws a `RecordNotFoundException`. This makes sense, since it’s looking for an entry that does no exist.

I was hoping switching from `firstOrFail` to `find` in the `EntriesController` would allow the application to continue with the next route in line (because no exception would be thrown), but the result is actually worse: It tries to render the entry view without an object, causing PHP notices on an otherwise empty layout.

I have read the CakePHP documentation (“Book”), but could not find a solution to this (I would assume rather generic) problem. I have also tried many other (often less obvious) route setups, but no luck there either.

Now my mind keeps going to something like a `EntryOrUserController`, but I doubt that would be the best solution, or even a good one. Frankly, I think it’s silly. I guess I am really hoping for some controller or middleware function that does exactly what I want out of the box, but any elegant solution would do.

P.S. I do realize that the default CakePHP/MVC way of going about this would be to have URLs a bit more like this:

- Entry: `https://example.com/entries/hello-world`
- User: `https://example.com/users/test-user`

…but that is not an option in this case, so thanks but no. ☺

Comment: One option would be a custom route class that tests for a records existence: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360539/mapping-slugs-from-database-in-routing**

Comment: Thanks, @ndm! I posted an answer based on my findings there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ndm for pointing me in the right direction. After some tinkering I have a solution that works nicely. Posting it here because it might be of use to others. There are three steps.

### 1. Create custom routing class

`/src/Routing/Route/SlugRoute.php`:

```
namespace App\Routing\Route;

use Cake\Routing\Route\Route;
use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;

class SlugRoute extends Route
{
    use LocatorAwareTrait;

    public function parse($url, $method = '')
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url, $method);

        if (!$params ||
            !isset($this->options['model']) ||
            !isset($this->options['pass'][0])
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        $count = $this
            ->tableLocator()
            ->get($this->options['model'])
            ->find()
            ->where([
                $this->options['pass'][0] => $params['pass'][0]
            ])
            ->count();

        if ($count !== 1) {
            return false;
        }

        return $params;
    }
}
```

### 2. Apply new routing class to relevant routes

```
$routes->connect('/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'Entries', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['pass' => ['slug', 'name'], 'routeClass' => 'SlugRoute', 'model' => 'Entries']
);

$routes->connect('/:username',
    ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['pass' => ['username'], 'routeClass' => 'SlugRoute', 'model' => 'Users']
);
```

### 3. Consider a few things

- I’m also telling the routes which models to use. It would probably be nice if the routing class figures this out by itself.
- The routing class assumes we want to do a lookup on the first value of the `pass` array. That’s fine in this case (with only `slug` and `username` being passed), but it’s not very transparent and easily broken.